# htmlsimpledomでamazonの商品情報を取得する

Tags: php

以下のようなコードで商品名が取れると思ったのですが、うまく取得できません。
詳しい方、ご教示下さい。よろしくお願い致します。

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url = "http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AF%E3%82%BF%E3%83%8B-%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B9-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8-3%E6%9C%AC%E7%B5%84-CB-250-OR/dp/B000AQY0L4/ref=zg_bs_3895771_1";

$html = file_get_html($url);

$title = $html->find('#productTitle');
var_dump($title);
```

Answer (score 1):

`find`メソッドは、そのままだと配列を返すので、
`$title = $html->find('#productTitle', 0);`
として、
あと
`echo $title;`
としてみるといいかと思います。